# Internet Explorer Z-Index Positioning Issue - Pushes content down

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I'm currently in the process of coding a site I have been working on for my father, and have come across an issue with the dreaded IE.

I have a slider at the top of the page, which has a dark transparent menu bar over the top, with a Z index applied to bring it to the front. It renders perfectly in all browsers, with the exception of IE on a PC.

The page should render like this:

http://cl.ly/GOCC

Note that the top of the burglars hat is visible under the transparent navigation bar.

In IE, it renders like this however:

http://cl.ly/GO6O

Note that it pushes the slider image down beneath the transparent navigation div (again, using the hat as a defence point).

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could rectify this? I'm not an experienced coder and not too great with IE fixes! I've searched the inter webs but to no avail... HELP!

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Plymstock Security Systems</h1>
                <ul id="navigationlinks">
                    <li><a href="#">Products & Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Recent Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="sliderarea">

            <div id="state1">

            </div>
            <img src="images/slider1.png" alt=""/>
        </div>

        <div class="contentarea">
        </div>
```

And CSS as follows:

```
.navigation {

position: relative;

z-index: 1991;

height: 140px;

background-repeat: repeat;
background-image: url(../images/navbgtrans.png);

}

.navigation h1 {
margin-left: -9px;
height: 140px;
width: 202px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url(../images/logo.png);
text-indent: -9999px;
}

ul#navigationlinks {
z-index: 0;
margin-top: -83px;
float: right;
list-style-type: none;
}

#navigationlinks li {
padding-left: 20px;
float: left;
}

#navigationlinks li a {
color: #bfbfbf;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: FreightSansBook;
text-decoration: none;
}

#navigationlinks li a:hover {
color: white;
}

#state1 {
background-image: url(../images/sliderbg1.png);
}
```

Many thanks in advance for any help you are able to offer me.

Comment: The source code can be viewed here: http://chopapp.com/#6xlgsaao, along with the CSS here: http://chopapp.com/#lkgz2xm9.

Comment: Luke, you should put your image and source code here (just the substancial part, of course). Providing links won't help other members with a similar problem after the links were broken.

Comment: Sorry Jaime - new here and just copied my post over from Forrst for ease. I'll update the post now.

Comment: Updated - can't embed images because I require more reputation points.

Comment: try making navigation's position absolute, top: 0, left: 0
That worked for me last time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ParthThakkar, but it made it worse in other browsers too: http://cl.ly/GOhi

Comment: ohk!!!! sorry. I take it back. :)

Comment: btw, did you insert semi-colons or directly pasted the code?

Comment: @ParthThakkar: In the code pasted above, that was directly copied and pasted from Coda. I manually entered your suggestion changing .navigation's position: relative to position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;.

Comment: @ParthThakkar: Solved it - thanks for your help. I needed to apply those styles to #sliderarea - seems to render fine now, although it's a bit weird when the page loads (loads in the top left corner of browser then moves down).

Comment: Please add the solution as answer and accept it so others know its solved :)

Comment: @benni_mac_b - I would, but as a newbie it won't even let me do that for 8 hours. Geez these rules are strict -.-